# Import multiple text files into single 2 column SQL table (Filename, Text Content)

Tags: sql-server, import, docx

I have a folder containing thousands of text files (.txt) that I want to import into a single SQL Server table with the following 2 fields:

```
Filename
Content
```

Filename = filename of the text file

Content = the text within the text file

I'm hoping there is an easy(ish) way to do this using maybe a command line utility or through SSIS or just through T-SQL as I ultimately want to add this into a SQL job to run on a schedule.

Would somebody please point in the right direction and possibly provide an example?

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried something so far? Have you find something over the internet?

Comment: SSIS can loop through the files yes. I assume that all the files have the same definition? Knowing how far you've got so far with your attempt(s) will greatly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like below:

```
INSERT INTO YourTable (FileName, Content)
SELECT 'mytxtfile.txt',BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'c:\temp\mytxtfile.txt', SINGLE_CLOB) MyFile
```

Refer here [BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET(BULK…)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I've combined it with xp_dirtree and some T-SQL to loop through the files in the folder, importing one at a time. Thanks!